# WinJS.Resources.getString with non-WinRT apps

Tags: cordova, localization, windows-runtime, winjs

I am using WinJS 4.0 to develop a Cordova app. But I tried to use WinJS.Resources.getString but it is not working. It works perfectly with my Windows 8.1 apps.
Is there any ways that I can use this with Cordova? If not, which alternative solution should I use? Please give me an answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that but not directly.

Before calling WinJS.UI.processAll you have to read resjson and set the global "strings" variable:

```
var loadLocalRessources = function (language) {
   language = language || 'en';
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete, error) {
        var url = './strings/' + language + '/resources.resjson';
        console.log('trying to load resources from ' + url);

        WinJS.xhr({ url: url }).then(function (res) {
            console.log('resource ok for ' + language);
            try {
                window.strings = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
            } catch (exception) {
                console.error('resource parse error ' + exception.message);
            }
            complete(window.strings);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error('resource load error for ' + language + ' ' + err.statusText);
            if (language != 'en') {
                data.loadLocalRessources('en').then(complete, error);
            }
            else {
                error(err);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

http://mcnextpost.com/2015/03/05/how-to-use-winjs-resources-with-a-cordova-app/